# Percentage padding not responding to browser width

Tags: html, css

I'd like to give some `li`'s in my code padding that is responsive, which either increases or decreases depending on the browser width.

I thought this would be as simple as using `padding: 0 5%` but it doesn't work, that results in a padding of `7.063px` which does not change if the browser increases or decreases in size.

```css
.wrapper > * { 
  display: inline-block 
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}


li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <h1>Hello</h1>
 <ul>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
  <li>Pears</li>
 </ul>
 <h1>Bye</h1>
</div>
```

What am I missing, is this not how padding is supposed to work with percentages?  How can I achieve responsive padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%` is about `parent` not browser size

So try to use `vw`:

[Working code](https://jsfiddle.net/360fsdhx/)

```css
.wrapper > * { 
  display: inline-block 
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}


li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <h1>Hello</h1>
 <ul>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
  <li>Pears</li>
 </ul>
 <h1>Bye</h1>
</div>
```

**Other way** is to set `width` to parent

[See working code:](https://jsfiddle.net/360fsdhx/2/)

```css
.wrapper > * { 
  display: inline-block 
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  width:80%;
}


li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <h1>Hello</h1>
 <ul>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
  <li>Pears</li>
 </ul>
 <h1>Bye</h1>
</div>
```